# Can I know the name of the class that calls a JNI C method?

Tags: java, c, class, java-native-interface

Is there any way I can know the name of the class that called a method in JNI C code ? I can obtain a reference to the class using the following statement :

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);
```

But is there any way I can know the name of the class ? .

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This code will give you the calling class name:

```c
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

// First get the class object
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");
jobject clsObj = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid);

// Now get the class object's class descriptor
cls = env->GetObjectClass(clsObj);

// Find the getName() method on the class object
mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// Call the getName() to get a jstring object back
jstring strObj = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(clsObj, mid);

// Now get the c string from the java jstring object
const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars(strObj, NULL);

// Print the class name
printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);

// Release the memory pinned char array
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strObj, str);
```

Note that I haven't taken any actions to check for errors. This is just a small code snippet describing how it could be done.

---

Alternatively you could do this instead of using the `GetStringUTFChars/ReleaseStringUTFChars`:

```
// Make sure that the buffer is large enough
char str[128];
jint strlen = env->GetStringUTFLength(strObj);
env->GetStringUTFRegion(strObj, 0, strlen, str);
printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);
```

No need to release since the string is copied to local buffer.

Comment: I think you shouldn't use strlen as a variable name since that's an existing standard C function.

Comment: In my experience, you don't actually need the steps under "First get the class object"; `clsObj` and `cls` are functionally equivalent.

Comment: The sample code is horrybly leaking local references if used "as is". All jobject and jclass references should be deleted. Also, this is a bad practice:

jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

...

cls = env->GetObjectClass(clsObj);

Without freeing the previous reference stored in cls.

Comment: @SergeyGalin No you are totally wrong. All references are local and the JVM will delete them when the native invocation ends. _To make sure that Java objects can eventually be freed, the JNI by default creates local references. Local references become invalid when the execution returns from the native method in which the local reference is created._

Comment: @SergeyGalin And also: _In most cases, the native programmer should rely on the VM to free all local references after the native method returns. In certain situations, however, the native code may need to call the DeleteLocalRef function to explicitly delete a local reference._ But none of the above calls needs to be deleted explicitly.

Comment: @maba, Actually, there is one scenario which you NEED to delete the local refs by youself, when your code is large enough and a lot of iterations are made. There is a limit of how much local refs could be created during a JNI call (512 only!). So, SergeyCalin is right when saying it is a good practice to free them as soon as they are done. (check the following questions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917777/jni-error-local-reference-table-overflow-512-entries and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019893/jni-local-reference-table-overflow-when-using-newglobalref)

Comment: Why is this line needed? `cls = env->GetObjectClass(clsObj);`  i.e. what is the difference between the class object and the class object's class descriptor?

Comment: @LukeHutchison You need the class descriptor to explore the methods on the class.  You can see on the different types that the class object is of type`jobject` while the class object descriptor is of type jclass.

Comment: @maba What is the difference between a `jclass` and a `jobject` that points to a `Class<?>` reference? How does `jobject clsObj = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid)` not just return the `Class<?>` reference for `Class.class`? Why doesn't `jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj)` immediately return the class of `obj`? Why is the second call to `GetObjectClass` even needed?

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I haven't had the object to get the class. Instead, I wanted to get the name of a given class, based on its signature.

So, this worked for me. I hope it can help:

```
// Find the class by its JNI signature
jclass cls = env->FindClass(expectedType);

// Get the class object's class descriptor
jclass clsClazz = env->GetObjectClass(cls);

// Find the getSimpleName() method in the class object
jmethodID methodId = env->GetMethodID(clsClazz, "getSimpleName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring className = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(cls, methodId);

// And finally, don't forget to release the JNI objects after usage!!!!
env->DeleteLocalRef(clsClazz);
env->DeleteLocalRef(cls);
```

Answer (score -3):

Just invoke `getName()` on the `jclass`, also via JNI.

Comment: you mean `( (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj) )->getName()` ? I want to print the name of the class (that invoked the method) from the jni c code

Comment: FYI - generally speaking, when you describe what you've done, and what error messages, etc... are preventing you from succeeding, you'll get better help.  EJP's response is correct.  Without knowing what error you are getting, we can't begin to comment about what's not working.  Remember that getName() is going to return a jstring...

Comment: @Y.E.P No I don't mean that. I mean what I said, and I said to do it 'via JNI'. In other words, get the methodID of getName(), call CallObjectMethod...(), etc.

Comment: @EJP I cannot get the methodID. I have been getting the exception as I try to get the methodID. The exception says , cannot find the particular method. So I wanted the name of the class to know whose class reference am I obtaining when I do `jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,obj);` so that I don't get an exception when I finally do `(*env)->GetMethodID(env,cls,"javaFunction","()V");`

Comment: @Y.E.P If you can't get the methodID of Class.getName() you are obviously doing something wrong.

Comment: @Y.E.P. And you have subsequently accepted an answer that does precisely this.