# JNI error : Local reference table overflow 512 entries

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

My function looks like below. And it is getting executed for a number of times.At certain point it is crashing at jobject nvarObject = env->GetObjectField (var1, nvar1) giving error JNI error : Local reference table overflow 512 entries.

Could anyone look into this issue and throw some light.

Comment: i am not sure when i should clean up the local references.I am trying to clean the local reference using (*env)->DeleteLocalRef( env, cls);     But still the issue is seen.

Comment: Are errors occurring that cause an early return from the function? In that case, you'll never hit the DeleteLocalRef() code. Make sure that the references are cleaned up before any return from this function, especially if it's called in a loop numerous times before returning control to the JVM.

Comment: yeah this function is getting executed for many times and after that at some point it is reaching till **jobject nplpidObject = env->GetObjectField (param, nplpids);** and it is crashing giving overflow error.

Comment: Ah yes. GetObjectField is also returning a reference (anything that's a Java object will be a reference). So you should delete that reference as well before exiting the function.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

All JNI methods that return a `jobject` or similar object reference are creating local references in the reference table. These references get automatically cleaned up when you return control to the JVM, but if you are creating many references (for instance, in a loop), you'll need to clean up them up manually.

You're on the right track by calling `DeleteLocalRef` on the `cls` reference, but notice that `GetObjectField` also returns a `jobject`, so the reference returned there should be deleted before exiting the function, as well.

Also make sure to clean up any existing references before returning from error conditions!

Another way to do this: at the top of the function that you're calling in a loop, call `PushLocalFrame( env, 5 )` and call `PopLocalFrame(env)` before any place in the function where you return. This will automatically clean up any references created during that function call. The second argument is the number of local references you want in the frame -- if you need more than 5 local references during the execution of the function, use a value higher than 5.

Comment: Can i clean the reference in the below way :                           **(*env)->DeleteLocalRef( env, nplpidobject);**                                  And also i have a doubt whether getfieldid also returns a reference.

Comment: Another handy way is to use `PushLocalFrame`/`PopLocalFrame`. When you call PopLocalFrame, and local references created after the last call to `PushLocalFrame` will be removed. That can be handier than keeping track of all places where you create a local ref.

Comment: I second that - Push/PopLocalFrame are easy and always work (and can be wrapped in C++ RAII), while manually figuring out where all the references are created is hard and inherently error-prone.

Comment: DeleteLocalRef for the jobject also i have done.But still the crash is seen...Inorder to use PushLocalFrame(env,size)...i dont know exactly how many references will be created insde that function internally..Is there any solution for that or should i blindly set the size to some value...

Comment: @rahulvenus It doesn't much matter what size you pass. If it succeeds you are guaranteed to be able to create that number of references - but normally creating more than you asked for is fine, unless you manage to run out of memory completely.

Comment: Where does the 512 limit comes from?

Comment: Just thought of mentioning that the issue was due to leakage in some other component in the same thread and when it was reaching my component, it was failing to create more references since it already exceeded 512 entries. Once the cleanup happened ( I mean after removing the local references after each usage) , the issue got solved. Thanks for all your help and it helped me a lot that time to debug and sorry for the late reply.