# VM aborting Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)

Tags: android, cordova

**VM aborting

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)

Failed adding to JNI local ref table (has 512 entries)

JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)**

I'm getting the above error when my app crashes..I'm not inserting any data into the DB. I'm getting the data from DB and processing it. For 10 times it is working but at the 11th time it is crashing.. It works fine on Jelly bean and above versions but it is not working on 4.0.4(Ice Cream Sandwich) version.

Any Idea?

Comment: Looks like too many local references, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917777/jni-error-local-reference-table-overflow-512-entries