# JNI: how to check that two jclass instances actually refer to the same Java class?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a bit of a problem with my JNI native code on Android 6 (ART). I've got a method that receives a `jclass` instance and stores this class reference for future use. To do that, I need to create a reference to this `jclass` so that it doesn't become invalid later:

```
std::set<jclass> storedClasses;

void storeClass(jclass cls)
{
   TraceLog << "Original jclass:" << cls;
   jclass clsRef = (jclass)env.jniEnv()->NewGlobalRef(cls);
   TraceLog << "New jclass global reference:" << cls;

   storedClasses.insert(clsRef);
}
```

The caveat is that I need to only store each class **once** (hence the choice of `std::set` for a container - it guarantees that all the items are unique), but `NewGlobalRef` actually creates a new, different `jclass` value every time. That makes sense, but it was not the case until recently, I believe. I can no longer use this value itself (which is simply a pointer) to ensure uniqueness.

How can I check whether two different `jclass` instances point to the same or different Java classes? Will casting `jclass` back to `jobject` and calling `java.lang.Object.hashcode` on it yield the desired result?

**Update:** odd, I can call `hashcode()` successfully, but it always returns `-1`.
**Update 2:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26361005/634821) does not work either, all I get is `java.lang.Class` no matter how I try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewGlobalRef` creates a new reference, not a new object nor instance of the class object.  If you call it twice you will get two different values, neither of which will be the same as the local reference you got initially.  The `IsSameObject` call will tell you that they all refer to the same thing, and is the only reliable way to determine if two references point to the same object.

You can't trivially create a set with the references because the references aren't unique.  If your only requirement is to avoid adding a duplicate object, you can do an O(n) series of `IsSameObject` calls when adding a new member.  Use hash codes with caution -- the hash code for an object won't change, so if the hash codes don't match you have two different objects, but two different objects can have the same hash code.

An alternative approach would be to use JNI calls to store your class objects in a Java-language data structure like a HashSet; this adds additional overhead for the JNI calls, but if you're storing a large number of objects the improved data structure could be beneficial.

(Trivia: pre-ICS, Dalvik would simply return a pointer to the referenced object, so you could actually create a native set trivially.  This approach made fancy heap management harder, so the ICS release introduced "indirect" references, which are augmented table indices rather than pointers.)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a lot more about JNI! And yeah, I remember a ton of JNI bugs that occurred in my app when ICS came out. And a ton of fun I've had fixing them :)

Comment: P. S. Can you please clarify how two different objects can have the same hash code? I mean, do you refer to the probabilistic nature of hashes and the fact that collision is not impossible, or do you mean that it actually may happen in a real app with statistically significant probability?

Comment: If the hash code is computed (e.g. `java.lang.String`), two *equal* objects will always have the same hash. For a simple Object the hash code is typically set to the object's 32-bit address, and "locked in" the first time something requests it (so it stays consistent if the object is moved). This avoids having to explicitly keep a hash code in objects that are never stored in hashed containers. Depending on the GC characteristics, it may be likely for objects to be created in a small range of addresses, making collisions probable. I don't know how ART works though.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, and then explaining that. I do use hashes for another container that holds `Object`s my app is interacting with. I realize it's a different topic entirely, but could you suggest a more reliable mechanism of distinguishing between generic objects (and recognizing equal ones)?

Comment: There is no "unique ID", neither in native nor Java language code. The hash code is a useful optimization, but even in Java you have to check for uniqueness with `==` or `equals()`. For your own objects you can add a unique ID field with a serial number and just do a direct field lookup from JNI (which will be fast).

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is that you are storing `clsRef`, which is a `jobject` you cast to a `jclass`.  It's not really a `jclass`, but a different object that is a reference to your original class.

You need to store something that acts as a key for that global ref in your store.  That something must uniquely identify the class.

Your store is a set, and I think you need, e.g. a hash table.

If `FindClass()` returns identical values for the same parameters each time then that could be used, but I cannot test that at the moment.  I suspect you need to do a `GetName()`, but, again, can't text it now.

Comment: I tried `GetName` (see Update 2 in my Q), and it returns `lang.Class` even for the original `cls`, which is the actual original class that my JNI method receives.