# JNI GetLongField failed with "jni not valid for an object of class java.lang.Class"

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

java code:

```
public class Foo {
    private long i = 0;
    void printI() {
        nativePrintI();
    }      
    private native static void nativePrintI();
}
```

JNI code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_aliyun_livestream_Publisher_nativeRelease
    (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj) {
    jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);;
    jfieldID iField = env->GetFieldID(cls, "i", "J");
    jlong i = env->GetLongField(obj, iField);
    printf("%lld\n", i);
}
```

my callee like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.printI();
```

sometimes It works fine, but sometimes It failed with message ""jni not valid for an object of class java.lang.Class"

Comment: Where is the native code for `nativePrintI()`? and what does the native code for `nativeRelease()` have to do with it?

Answer (score 6):

When you declare a `native` method as `static`, the corresponding JNI function will receive a `JNIEnv*` and a `jclass`, plus whatever additional arguments you have specified (in this case none). The `jclass` argument is a reference to the class on which the method was invoked.
This is really no different from calls you make within Java; when you call a `static` method it will be invoked on a class rather than an object instantiated from that class.

A non-static `native` method on the other hand will call the JNI function with a `JNIEnv*` and a `jobject`, where the `jobject` is a reference to the object on which the method was invoked.

In C/C++, a `jobject` and a `jclass` are both pointers, so you'll be able to assign one to the other, but when you try to pass or return them to a Java/JNI function it will matter what kind of underlying values those pointers point to.
`GetObjectClass` and `GetLongField` expect that you pass them a `jobject`, so the `jclass` that you get in the `static` case will not work.

If you want a `jobject`, declare the method as non-static in Java. If you want a `jclass`, declare the method as static in Java. If you want both, declare it non-static so that you receive a `jobject` which you then can call `GetObjectClass` on.

Answer (score 1):

use snippets from [Can I know the name of the class that calls a JNI C method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719766/can-i-know-the-name-of-the-class-that-calls-a-jni-c-method)

```
jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);

// First get the class object
jmethodID mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");
jobject clsObj = env->CallObjectMethod(obj, mid);

// Now get the class object's class descriptor
cls = env->GetObjectClass(clsObj);

// Find the getName() method on the class object
mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// Call the getName() to get a jstring object back
jstring strObj = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(clsObj, mid);

// Now get the c string from the java jstring object
const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars(strObj, NULL);

// Print the class name
printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);

// Release the memory pinned char array
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strObj, str);
```

It turns out, when the Calling class name is "java.lang.Class", `GetLongField` fails. yet, when the Calling class name is "Foo", `GetLongField` succeed.

Maybe it's due to Java's GC mechanism. Because the function `nativePrintI` is defined as static function. Java sometimes will call it without the valid Instance.

so change `nativePrintI` to `private native void nativePrintI();` can solve the problems.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @EJP change the definition of nativePrintI will fix this