# How to obtain the name of a Java class from its corresponding jclass?

Tags: java-native-interface, jnienv

I have a `jclass` and I need to find out the name of the corresponding Java class. There is a well-received answer on SO for a similar question, however, it requires an object that's an instance of this class: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730789/634821

I don't always have an instance where having the name of a `jclass` would be very useful, and I find it hard to believe that Java has no way to find a class's name, which is obviously a static property, with only static methods. So, is it doable, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `jclass` is a `jobject` subclass that references a java `Class` object.

So, cut the first few lines off the answer you found:

```
jclass input = ...; // Class<T>
jclass cls_Class = env->GetObjectClass(input); // Class<Class>

// Find the getName() method on the class object
mid = env->GetMethodID(cls_Class, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

// Call the getName() to get a jstring object back
jstring strObj = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(input, mid);

// Now get the c string from the java jstring object
const char* str = env->GetStringUTFChars(strObj, NULL);

// Print the class name
printf("\nCalling class is: %s\n", str);

// Release the memory pinned char array
env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strObj, str);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, saved my day! Works like charm. I was just starting to wonder what `jclass` is and what I can do with it besides `FindMethod`, and boom - your answer explained everything. I don't actually remember reading this anywhere in the JNI docs, but I may have just missed it.

Comment: See [this part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html#reference_types) of the jni documentation