# GetMethodID for "getName" is returning NULL

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have been trying to print out the class name from a jclass object.

`jmethodID mid_getName = env->GetMethodID(point_class, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");`

The `point_class` object is not NULL.

I used this snippet from [Can I know the name of the class that calls a JNI C method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719766/can-i-know-the-name-of-the-class-that-calls-a-jni-c-method) and [Class name from jclass in JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9265457/class-name-from-jclass-in-jni)

On another note, I am doing JNI programming for android and my `FindClass` method is returning NULL when I want to create Java object on the native side. No proguard issue or anything else.

Code:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL long_JNI_method_name (JNIEnv * env, jobject object, jlong image, jint screenHeight, jint screenWidth) {

jclass point_class = env->GetObjectClass(object);
jmethodID mid_getName = env->GetMethodID(point_class, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
...
```

I changed the JNI method name as it had package name(where I work) in it.

Comment: Post all of *your* code.  You're leaving something out.

Comment: Posted the source code.

Answer (score 2):

You try to get method `getName()` of the `object`. But the object (and your class derived from object) does not have method `getName()`. The `getName()` is a method of the class `Class`. Your problem is like you try to call

```
anObject.getName();
```

instead of correct

```
anObject.getClass().getName();
```

The corresponding C++ code must get the call `getClass` first and the it can search for `getName` and it may looks like:

```
jclass    point_class = env->GetObjectClass(object);
jmethodID getclass    = env->GetMethodID(point_class, "getClass", "()Ljava/lang/Class;");
jobject   classsObj   = env->CallObjectMethod(object, getclass);
jclass    classclass  = env->GetObjectClass(classsObj);
jmethodID mid_getName = env->GetMethodID(classclass, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This suggestion saved me.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly simpler version:

```
jclass object_class = env->GetObjectClass(object);
jclass class_class = env->GetObjectClass(object_class);
jmethodID mid_getName = env->GetMethodID(class_class, "getName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

Comment: env->GetObjectClass(object_class) may also be replaced by env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");